# Constraint grease pencil strokes

Tags: animation, constraints

I am a scholar of using blender. I have a situation-i'am using a grease pencil on surface and alembic sequence. So here is the question. Can i constraint drawn strokes to mesh for several frames and redraw shape of it. You can watch a clip from Spider-man: Into to Spider-verse to understand exactly what i mean.

https://youtu.be/vDjvhwgbsP8

Thanks for support!

Comment: I think I am in a similar situation. Wanting something between the old 2.79 "stick to surface" system crossed with the slide projector image thing from the manual (to create 2D facial expressions on a 3D mesh)?